# Apps Script JDBC reads DATETIME with wrong timezone

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to read from a `DATETIME` field in MySQL using the Apps Script JDBC service. The database has its timezone set to UTC (`@@global.time_zone` == `@@session.time_zone` == `'+00:00'`), and I've double-checked this by doing `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COL) FROM TABLE`. My script is also set to use UTC.

However, when I read the value from the JDBC result set using `getTimestamp`, it is skewed forwards by 8 hours. This occurs regardless of whether I pass a timezone to `getTimestamp` (indeed, there is no change whatsoever, regardless of what timezone I pass), and regardless of whether `useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift` is enabled or not.

If I read the result using `getString`, it gives the correct time (in UTC). Barring using `getString` and parsing it into a JavaScript `Date`, how can I fix this issue?

**Edit**

Here's a testing script I used, and its output:

```js
export function tzTest(): void {
    const dbIp = DB_IP
    const dbPw = DB_PW

    let conn = Jdbc.getConnection(`jdbc:mysql://${dbIp}/mydb`, { user: "myuser", password: dbPw })
    let stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COL FROM MYTABLE WHERE OWNER_ID=1")
    stmt.execute()
    let res = stmt.getResultSet()
    res.next()

    console.log("==== DEFAULT ====")

    console.log("=== getTimestamp ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getTimestamp(1).getTime())} (${res.getTimestamp(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getTimestamp(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getTimestamp(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)

    console.log("=== getTime ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getTime(1).getTime())} (${res.getTime(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getTime(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getTime(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)

    console.log("=== getDate ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getDate(1).getTime())} (${res.getDate(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getDate(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getDate(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)
    conn.close()

    conn = Jdbc.getConnection(`jdbc:mysql://${dbIp}/mydb`, { user: "myuser", password: dbPw, useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift: true })
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COL FROM MYTABLE WHERE OWNER_ID=1")
    stmt.execute()
    res = stmt.getResultSet()
    res.next()

    console.log("==== useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift ====")

    console.log("=== getTimestamp ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getTimestamp(1).getTime())} (${res.getTimestamp(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getTimestamp(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getTimestamp(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)

    console.log("=== getTime ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getTime(1).getTime())} (${res.getTime(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getTime(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getTime(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)

    console.log("=== getDate ===")
    console.log(`plain: ${new Date(res.getDate(1).getTime())} (${res.getDate(1).getTime()})`)
    console.log(`utc: ${new Date(res.getDate(1, "UTC").getTime())} (${res.getDate(1, "UTC").getTime()})`)
    conn.close()
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
==== DEFAULT ====
=== getTimestamp ===
plain: Sat Dec 21 2019 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576942757000)
utc: Sat Dec 21 2019 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576942757000)
=== getTime ===
plain: Thu Jan 01 1970 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (56357000)
utc: Thu Jan 01 1970 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (56357000)
=== getDate ===
plain: Sat Dec 21 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576915200000)
utc: Sat Dec 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576886400000)
==== useJDBCCompliantTimeZoneShift ====
=== getTimestamp ===
plain: Sat Dec 21 2019 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576942757000)
utc: Sat Dec 21 2019 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576942757000)
=== getTime ===
plain: Thu Jan 01 1970 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (56357000)
utc: Thu Jan 01 1970 15:39:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (56357000)
=== getDate ===
plain: Sat Dec 21 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576915200000)
utc: Sat Dec 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) (1576886400000)
```

For comparison, `SELECT COL,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COL) * 1000) FROM MYTABLE WHERE OWNER_ID=1` gives `2019-12-21 07:39:17` and `1576913957000`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be a bug in the [past](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1642) and should already be fixed.

Including `useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true` in the connection parameter should fix the issue to interpret the timezone correctly.

Noting here that the timezone shown when converting a JavaScript Date to a string will always be the timezone of the server (in this case UTC) that's why your workaround fixed it.

Comment: As I noted in the original question, `useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift` appears to have no effect one way or the other.

Comment: @AlexO'Brien, can you try adding `serverTimezone=UTC` explicitly in the connection string?

Comment: @AlexO'Brien, for testing purposes, can you try other parameters for timezone such as other short IDs (PST, EST, and GMT), long IDs (US/Pacific and America/Los_Angeles), and offsets (GMT+6:30) if they properly show the correct timezone

Comment: I tried setting `serverTimezone=UTC` in the connection string, and received the error `Exception: The following connection properties are unsupported: serverTimezone.` in response.

Where do you want me to try those other parameters? If you meant for `serverTimezone`, well, the previous error means I can't try that. I tried an assortment of different options for the second argument to `getTimestamp`, and saw no change to their returned times.

Comment: It seems it is still isn't supported @AlexO'Brien under options based on the documentation. and as for the connection string, as you tested, it doesn't work. At the moment, it might be best to use the workaround, and file the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: I see. Well, thanks for your help investigating. I'll definitely file an issue. In case anyone else has the same problem, another potential workaround is to use `getDate` to detect the shift, and then simply subtract that from anything returned from `getTimestamp`.

Comment: Issue filed [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201557282).